# How to run .NET 4.5 on XSP using Mono?

Tags: c#, linux, mono, xsp

I have installed Mono 3 however when I run `xsp` or `xsp4` it shows that I'm using .NET 4.0. I need to have .NET 4.5. Is it possible? Where can I configure it?

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14244779/unable-to-run-an-asp-net-4-5-app-on-xsp-on-mono-3) page but I don't have any of those folders where I downloaded sources.

This is what it shows when I enter website by running `xsp4`:

> Version Information: 3.2.7 (master/1eef047 C  nov 28 18:16:30 EET 2013); ASP.NET Version: 4.0.30319.17020

## How I installed Mono and XSP

Firstly I downloaded Lubuntu 13.10 32bit and launched it inside VirtualBox. Then did `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade`. After that rebooted the system.

Make sure all commands are executed as super user.

```
sudo -s
```

Got dependencies

```
apt-get install autoconf automake libtool g++ gettext libglib2.0-dev libpng12-dev libfontconfig1-dev mono-gmcs git
```

Downloaded sources of Mono and XSP

```
cd /opt
git clone git://github.com/mono/mono.git
git clone git://github.com/mono/xsp.git
```

Installed latest stable Mono from github

```
cd /opt/mono
./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr
make
make install
```

Installed latest stable XSP from github

```
cd /opt/xsp
./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr
make
make install
```

Tested that I have 4.0 running on XSP instead of 4.5

```
cd /home/pc/web
xsp4 # 4.0
xsp2 # 2.0
xsp  # 2.0
```

## My configuration

`/usr/bin/xsp4` looks like it should use 4.5. Just like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15639165/440611) answer suggested. Also, I don't have `xsp4.exe` in my `/usr/lib/mono/4.0/` only in `/usr/lib/mono/4.5/` so I cannot copy anything like suggested in that answer.

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /usr/bin/mono $MONO_OPTIONS "/usr/lib/mono/4.5/xsp4.exe" "$@"
```

Comment: to be able to answer your question, you need to tell us how did you install mono 3, how did you install xsp, and what Linux distribution and version you have

Comment: @knocte Okey, right now I'm doing everything from scratch because I broke something. Once I'm done I will tell exact steps I followed.

Comment: @knocte okey i've added step by step how i installed xsp and mono.

Comment: did you uninstall xsp and mono ubuntu packages before installing the new mono from github?

Comment: You don't have `/opt/mono/bin/xsp4`? That's what's being edited to make mono run 4.5 in the linked question.

Comment: @bzlm he's installing in /usr, not /opt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say "I don't have any of those folders where I downloaded sources" referring to `/opt/mono/bin/xsp4`. But you're confusing things, and I know it because you shared how you installed mono.

`/opt/mono` should not be the place where you clone the mono repository to compile it. You should clone it somewhere else like your home folder. I.e.: /home/username/code/mono.

`/opt/mono` is where usually people install a custom version of mono. The way they do it is passing this path to the --prefix argument. But you're passing /usr as the prefix argument! So then you're installing it to a different location compared to the SO answer that you point out.

Also, it is not recommended that you do ALL those operations as a superuser. You normally compile code without root privileges, and you only need sudo for the install phase. So don't do "sudo -s" before everything. Just compile, and when you're done, do `sudo make install`. This will also make you have binaries that are not owned by root.

Comment: I just checked and you're correct. Similar things applies, just different paths. However it still does not work and configuration seems to be correct since it's pointing to xsp4 inside 4.5 directory. I've added configuration in my question. When I run it directly via `/usr/lib/mono/4.5/xsp4.exe` it still is 4.0 :(

Comment: I suggest that you post a new question since this one is too cluttered with installation and path details; we will be able to help easily in the new question

Comment: I don't think it's a configuration fault. XSP just can't run .NET 4.5 websites it seems. I've contacted several people and they all told me they just gave up on this matter.

Comment: I suggest that you post a new question

Comment: Okey, I've posted question as my final hope. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20312489/can-xsp-run-asp-net-4-5