# Can XSP run ASP.NET 4.5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mono, xsp

I've been trying to launch MVC5 (depends on .NET 4.5) under Mono for days now and with no success.

## Configuration

- Clean install of latest Lubuntu
- No previous XSP/Mono
- Compile and install XSP/Mono from latest git sources
- Mono version: 3.2.7

## Problem

When I run `xsp4` on any folder it shows `Version Information: 3.2.7 (master/1eef047 C nov 28 18:16:30 EET 2013); ASP.NET Version: 4.0.30319.17020`.

Latest Mono version supports .NET 4.5, does XSP?

If so, how can I make sure that it is using 4.5 instead of 4.0?

Even if I run XSP directly from Mono 4.5 folder (`/usr/lib/mono/4.5/xsp4.exe`) it shows ASP.NET version is 4.0.

Also, XSP config line in `/usr/bin/xsp4` looks like so. I'm very confused.

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /usr/bin/mono $MONO_OPTIONS "/usr/lib/mono/4.5/xsp4.exe" "$@"
```

Comment: **it does not work** is not a statement that is clear enough for stackoverflow, please describe why do you think it doesn't work? does it throw an error? does the page appear blank in the browser? what makes you think that it doesn't work?

Comment: @knocte It runs `ASP.NET Version: 4.0.30319.17020`, I need `ASP.NET Version: 4.5...`. There is no error. The version is not what I expect.

Comment: how are you extracting that version information?

Comment: On my instances of Mono I had to update my symlinks to the correct version of Mono. This could be a starting point for you to look at.

Comment: @knocte Since it shows 404 exception on empty folder it gives me information about mono and .net version on the bottom like in every standard exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can instruct mono to launch a particular runtime version with the  `--runtime` flag. In this case, it would be this way:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /usr/bin/mono $MONO_OPTIONS --runtime=v4.5 "/usr/lib/mono/4.5/xsp4.exe" "$@"
```

However, as far as I understand, the 4.5 profile of .NET doesn't include changes in the runtime, but in the class libraries and compilers. So if the above doesn't work, it simply means that the version of the runtime that one needs to use to run a 4.5 application is simply the **4.0.30319** version.

The best way to understand this is to include this little image diagram grabbed from a [Scott Hanselman's blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NETVersioningAndMultiTargetingNET45IsAnInplaceUpgradeToNET40.aspx):

[image]

Comment: `WARNING: The runtime version supported by this application is unavailable.`. Anyway, I think you might be right and it can run .NET 4.5 websites. I'm not sure how to test it tho.

Comment: Yes, I just tested it with different stack (not MVC5) and it did work with no problems. Also I made sure it is running .NET 4.5 underneath by checking if `System.Reflection.ReflectionContext` is present. And it was. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The only chance you can run MVC is to install mono 3.4.0.
mono 3.2.7 won't work for MVC5

Comment: You're right. However newset mono from git still does not support MVC5. (attribute routing, lower-case urls, other things..)

Answer (score 0):

I had followed this with  mono 3.4.0 and successfully set up a very simple MVC5 under MonoDevelop,

http://curtis.schlak.com/2014/02/04/setup-asp-net-mvc-4-on-monodevelop-4.2.html