# How can mod_mono be configured to run .NET 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, mono, mod-mono

I've been searching for days now, but still have not been able to find a way to get mod_mono to run .NET 4.5 web applications.

I've tried this and many other with no luck: [Can XSP run ASP.NET 4.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20312489/can-xsp-run-asp-net-4-5)

Currently, I have a functioning Ubuntu 14.04 Server running mono 3.6.1 that is able to server .Net 4 applications:

**Does anyone know how to configure mod_mono to run .NET 4.5?**

---

My test site is a simple page with the following code, `http://54.208.241.43/test.aspx`.

```
<%=System.Environment.Version%>
```

Comment: Where did you get mono 3.6.1? My Ubuntu 14.04 has mono 3.2.8.

Comment: Compiled from http://www.github.com/mono/mono/.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/tpokorra:/mono/xUbuntu_14.04/ /' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-opt.list"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mod_mono-opt
```

See these for more details
http://www.pokorra.de/2013/12/

Comment: I'm not confident this will provide a solution. Can you explain how this will solve the issue?